# Related to Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have made 2 smart contracts to receive the sent ethers and then send it to specific wallet addresses.

**First Smart Contract behavior.**
When contractaddress.transfer(value) is being executed, it consumes only 9700 gas.
Trx hash - 0xb92aa187b9d6713f9f36ce5ce2edf00108703a9e9cf572d9a5143bb1631f98cb

**Second Smart Contract behavior.**
When contractaddress.transfer(value) is being executed, it consumes 34700 gas.
Trx hash - 0xa5d22d4db05f6851bb52a06ea2eefc12d75f242ee476f9dee3594c988b75eaa5

Why are these 2 so different? I have compiled and deployed them using Remix IDE.

Note: Above 2 contracts uses different sets of wallet addresses. I am trying to use nanopool and gaslimit provided by them is only 50k which is insufficient for Second Smart Contract since its behavior changes.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Post the code for both contracts if you want a definitive answer, but my guess is that since two different contracts can have completely different implementations of the `transfer()` method, it will have different gas usage. One contract may just accept the ether and be done with the transaction, the other may be making several state changes to go along with it, thus consuming more gas.

Comment: I second posting your code. Depending on the inner workings of both contracts you might have a "gas" leak. Edit: BTW is "gas" leak a thing in Solidity development?